# Deleting (latest) revision of file on Google Drive gives 500 Internal Error - How to fix?

Tags: google-drive-api

Because of a malware attack a lot of files on our Google Drives got corrupted. Luckily it should be able to revert these files to the revision prior to the attack.

Using v3 or v2 of the Drive API, I list the revisions of each affected file. Again using the API, I delete the latest revision (the one that is corrupt) using a call like DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/11uTTqqrNErTglRGjqfWxwl0TnuoIVPQ3/revisions/0Bwt_TcYWSupqRDZiUDhDRVQ0cWF0RTBSQnNkMk5vbDg3TWowPQ.

Even using the "Try this API" on the Google reference page, I get 500 Internal Error. I tried multiple binary files. I can't imagine an overflow of server requests.

EDIT: Using the same workflow it works perfectly for a bunch of files, but for some (.BAK files, though other .BAK files don't give the error) the response code is consistently 500.

What might be causing this error? Is it not possible to delete the latest revision?

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.  How are you creating the authorization header how are you sending this request?

Comment: Does this happen with every file you are trying to delete the revision from? Is it a consistent behavior? I had tried reproducing this but with no success as I ended up getting a 204 and the revision being deleted accordingly.

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect that I use the required authorization (it works for other files on the same shared Drive) and to reflect that it happens consistently only with 700 or so of 11000 files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ale13 mentions, it is probably related to my specific situation.

I "solved" the problem of the files that gave 500 error by reuploading the revision prior to the attack to the same file, using the downloadUrl when listing revisions (API v2) for downloading and using PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/*fileid*?uploadType=multipart&supportsAllDrives=true for (re)uploading.

Answer (score 0):

**Since what you are describing seems to be in fact related to your specific domain and situation, the best thing to do is to contact Google Workspace Support.**

Depending on the subscription you have, I suggest you choose one of the options from this link [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213).

Answer (score 0):

I'm having exactly the same problem.

I run a Python script to delete specific versions from about 79,000 files and got errors for more than 2,200 of them. From the Python exception I get the following error message:

```
<HttpError 500 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/.../revisions/...? returned "Internal Error". Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'internalError', 'message': 'Internal Error'}]">
```

I tried the method in [its page](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/delete) and got the same results for a bunch of those same files.

I tried to delete those versions in the Google Drive web interface and I succeeded every time. But I can't do it by hand 2,000 times. ;)

I opened a case with Google but I was instructed to use StackOverflow... So,  understood the proposed "solution" but it really is more like a workaround. I'd like to know what is causing the errors and how they can be avoided in the first place.